# Multiple functions in PHP function_exists

Tags: php

Is there any way to have multiple functions inside function_exists?

I've tried:

```
if (function_exists('function_one' && 'function_two')) {
```

It doesn't return an error but returns false when both functions do exist.

Comment: `if (function_exists('function_one') || function_exists('function_two')) {` run the function twice with an or or an and as required

Comment: You need to call `function_exists` *individually* for each function name.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. If you pop this as the answer I'll accept :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what you did in the script was check if the function `function_onefunction_two` exists. If you want to fix that you can do this:

```
if(function_exists('function_one') && function_exists('function_two')) {
```

Comment: Actually, `('function_one' && 'function_two')` returns `true` (boolean);

Comment: Oh well, I didn't test it,  but the fix is sound